# Организация кода в проекте на Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, mvc, архитектура

*Вопрос к тем, кто делает большие и сложные проекты на Yii2 (или другом MVC-фреймворке).*

Какими принципами вы руководствуетесь, когда определяете, какой класс за что отвечает? Например, расширять ли модели, унаследованные от ActiveRecord (те самые, которые генерирует Gii) дополнительным кодом или оставить как сервис по преобразованию объекта в табличное представление и обратно?

Comment: Вы спрашиваете: расширять или не расширять. Мне кажется, вопрос должен выглядеть немного по-другому: "расширять или плодить". И тут может быть только один ответ: "расширять"

Comment: @MasterAlex, можно подробнее про плодить и расширять?

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от Вашего конкретного проекта. Общая идея такая: если в проекте присутствует сложная бизнес-логика, я бы советовал ее максимально отделить от работы с источником данных, оставляя логику предметной области независимой как от структуры хранения данных, так и от фреймворка (для того, чтобы минимизировать зависимость классов предметной области от используемого фреймворка, меры по типу "не прописывать бизнес-логику в наследниках от ActiveRecord" будут хорошим началом, но их будет недостаточно). Для относительно простых проектов подобная архитектура может оказаться оверкилом.

Отделяя бизнес-логику от доступа к данным, Вы получаете следующие преимущества:

1. Переносимость кода. Если в дальнейшем понадобится переписать проект под другой фреймворк, Вам это будет сделать проще. Если понадобится реализовать схожий по функционалу проект, но на другом фреймворке - опять же, это будет проще.
2. Тестируемость. Код, в котором минимум зависимостей, легче покрыть тестами, тесты будут более легкими, будут быстрее исполнятся.
3. Независимость от структуры хранения данных. Если Ваши классы не работают напрямую с доступом к данным, а лишь через посредника, то, в случае изменений в структуре данных, Вам не придется править код классов предметной области, а только код посредников.

Есть и другие преимущества, менее очевидные, но не менее полезные. Подобным образом организованное приложение будет более гибким. Все это является следствием соблюдения принципа единой ответственности (S в SOLID). И если находятся люди, которые считают принципы SOLID не состоятельными (лично я к таким не отношусь и советую всегда держать их в уме, если Вы строите сложное приложение, которое в дальнейшем планируется масштабировать, развивать и поддерживать), то как правило даже они соглашаются с тем, что принцип единой ответственности - важный принцип и он не столько даже SOLID, сколько просто здравый смысл, да и применяется он не только в контексте ООП парадигмы.

С другой стороны, ActiveRecord сам по себе является паттерном, который рекомендуется использовать только при работе с простой бизнес-логикой, поэтому может быть Вам лучше изначально обратить свое внимание в сторону ORM, которые реализуют паттерн DataMapper (Doctrine, Propel 2, Spot)? Ведь сам по себе Yii2 не обязывает использовать AR, как безальтернативный вариант.

Приведу так же и "недостатки" подхода, когда Вы отделяете бизнес-логику от доступа к данным:

1. Для работы с таким кодом, требуется более квалифицированная команда. По хорошему люди должны хорошо понимать принципы объектно-ориентированного дизайна и ни у кого не должны возникать вопросы "а зачем мы так изгаляемся? я раньше работал не так и было проще и удобнее".
2. Если разработчики не умеют работать с этим подходом, а просто бегут под знамя "отделить бизнес-логику потому что так правильно", получается очень плохо: ответственность классов начинает размываться, код становится нечитабельным, ни о какой лучшей переносимости, тестируемости речи быть и не может.
3. На разработку уходит больше времени (на самом деле не особо, если команда опытная).

Как видите большинство недостатков можно спихнуть на кривизну рук, с другой стороны на найм прямых рук, не всегда есть ресурсы.
Если вы пишите простенький блог - используйте АР и не заморачивайтесь, если вы пишите CRM, подумайте про паттерн DataMapper и старайтесь отделять бизнес-логику.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, хотелось бы только понять, как развести бизнес-логику и доступ к данным.  Живой пример очень помог бы.

Comment: советую почитать Мэтта Зандстру, раздел про паттерны доступа к данным (там как раз все объясняется с примерами на PHP). для более углубленного изучения вопроса советую Мартина Фаулера "Шаблоны корпоративных приложений"